# Ruby on Rails App production on heroku shows error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

The Post what i create that created but doesn't show on show page but when i move to root at there i shows . There are alot functionality added to app but how could i know that will they properly work or not . On my Local my App is working Fine but after deployment on heroku it gives error.Using heroku log is shows[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcCxM.png)

My page is [enter image description here][2]

My gemfile is[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kavfL.png)

My imagetag syntax used in show page is
[enter image description here][4]

I have used pg DB in production.
Please help me out to deploy my app.

Comment: The error is in your file `posts/show.html.haml` you are using a method image that does not exists in your class. Heroku detect automatically when you are doing wrong things in your code.

Comment: Run  `heroku logs -t` on your terminal to view the server logs. [Document](https://blog.heroku.com/logging-on-heroku#working-with-logs)

Answer (score 0):

The error tell that there is no method `image` on `nil` in `post/show.haml` (around line `22-24`). That means you call `image` on something that you think exists, but it does not exist.

What you need to do:

- look at that file
- find where do call image on *something*
- find where you load that *something*
- investigate why it is possible that this something does not exist and fix this **or** only call `image` if that something exists.

The second option might look like:

```
- if post
  = post.image
- else
  no post image
```